# Issue while trying to display data from my database

Tags: database, swiftui

I have created a SwiftUI app that try to get, and display, all usernames from my MongoDB database by sending a GET-request to my Node.js server. Even though I'm successfully receiving an answer from the server, my app is still not able to handle these answers correctly. I think this problem is about how I am trying to decode the JSON data that I'm receiving in my Swift app. This is, for example, what I get by sending a GET-request with ThunderClient or Postman:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "6580bbcd7cb47bfc6e2f27e8",
    "username": "John",
    "password": "doe",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "6580bd7a7cb47bfc6e2f27ef",
    "username": "Hello",
    "password": "world",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

This is why I think the problem is located in my Swift code:

```
struct Account: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var username: String
    var password: String
    var __v: Int
    
}
enum NetworkError: Error {
    case invalidURL
    case noData
    case decodingError
    case apiError(String)
    
}
class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var username: String = ""
    @Published var password: String = ""
    @Published var isLoginSuccessful: Bool = false
    
    // some code
 
    
   // some code
             
    func getAllAcounts(completion: @escaping (Result<[Account], NetworkError>) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/getAllUsers") else {
            completion(.failure(.invalidURL))
            return
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(.noData))
                return
            }

            do {
                let accounts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Account].self, from: data)
                completion(.success(accounts))
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(.decodingError))
            }

        }.resume()
    }

   
    
   
    }
```

And here is how I try to display the data:

```
struct LeaderboardScreen: View {
   
    @EnvironmentObject var userVM: UserViewModel
    @State var usernames: [Account] = []
  

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("See leaderboard") {
                print("Button pressed")
                userVM.getAllAcounts { result in
                    switch result {
                    case.success(let accounts):
                        self.usernames = accounts
                        
                        print("usernames: \(usernames)")
                        
                    
                    case.failure(let error):
                        print("Issue while fetching users: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        
                    }
                        
                }
                    
            }
            
            if !usernames.isEmpty {
                List(usernames, id: \.id) { username in
                    Text(username.username)
                    
                }
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            } else {
                Text("No usernames available")
            }
               
               
                
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what I get when running the program: `Issue when fetching users: The operation couldn’t be completed. (MyApiApp.NetworkError error 3.)`
Please help me as I'm kind of new to working with APIs and database, any help is appreciated a lot!

Comment: You should almost never used `localizedDescription`, which contains much less information than just printing the `error`. Print the `error` and then Google the message.

Comment: Yepp, I just got a lot better explanation of my error without using `localizedDescription`. @jnpdx

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is how I solved my problem: First of all, I removed `localizedDescription` as this prevented more information about the problem that I was facing. Then I added this to my code:

```swift
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "_id"
    case username
    case password
    case __v
}
```

This is neccesary as we tell our Swift model to match the JSON format.